# Use sweetalert2 with node.js and express.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, sweetalert2

I'm trying to use sweetalert2 in my project node and express.js plus the configuration is not successful I guess.

I am receiving the following message:

**swal is not defined**

**ReferenceError: swal is not defined**

**My Settings**

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
const Swal = require('sweetalert2');

router.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {

    Swal('Hello world!');

});
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt_br">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="text-center title-1"> Cad </h1>
    <form action="/add" method="post">
        <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "festiva",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "ejs": "~2.5.7",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.28.4"
  }
}
```

If someone can guide...

Comment: Have you installed the npm module? Try `npm install sweetalert2`

Comment: yes Jamie Syme, the installation was done with this command npm install --save sweetalert2.

I edited my question by adding my package.json

Comment: Are you including `index.js` in a script tag in your html somewhere? Or is it being run using node?

Comment: you can't swall in server (code behind.) if you want to show it then  call it in client side js file. for example you send form data to server  with ajax request and show swall after the response.

Comment: My goal @A.kadir olmez was to show a message by sweetalert when a record was saved successfully. So the way I did it is incorrect. You would have an example to demonstrate this functionality through the backend. I'm looking at the documentation of the libraries I'm working on to find out.

Comment: @Jaimie Syme There is no inclusion on the page. The index page has a route to the backend where I inserted the swol.

Answer (score 0):

SweetAlert2 appears to be a client-side library, but you're using it on the server in your example.

To get your example to work, and without getting to complicated, try the following:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt_br">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="text-center title-1"> Cad </h1>
    <button type="button" onclick="swal('Hello, world!')">
        Click me
    </button>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.28.2/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The script tag will include the library on the client, and will eliminate the need for any node/express.

Comment: It worked perfectly well. My doubt and for sure was my problem, is that I thought it would be possible to call the swol in the backend, for example, when a record was saved successfully.